# How to compare PM time with AM time (PM should be less than AM)

Tags: c#

I have two dates that I am trying to compare:

a) 2019-09-22T23:40:00.000+04:00
b) 02:00

Both are strings that I am converting into a TimeSpan object.

I want (a) to be less than (b) because 11pm is before 2am but it is returning false rather than true, code shown below

```cs
DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-09-22T23:40:00.000+04:00").TimeOfDay <= TimeSpan.ParseExact("02:00", "hh\\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Code above should return true but is returning false instead.

Edit: Sorry to confuse people, to summarize:

I have a date in the following format:

2019-09-22T23:40:00.000+04:00

I have a time range in the following format:

17:00-02:00

Since 23:40 falls between 17:00 and 02:00 my code should return true.

Comment: How is 11pm *before* 2am?

Comment: @Diado I've read that other way round.

Comment: For that to be true, you'd need the 2am date to be the next day at least. Otherwise, 2pm will always be before 11pm - that's like saying 23 comes before 2.

Comment: "I have two dates that I am trying to compare" - no, you have one date/time with an offset, and one time-of-day. Those aren't the same thing. It's very unclear why you expect 11pm to be before 2am. Is 11pm before 10:30pm as well? What *exact* rules are you trying to follow here?

Comment: Maybe its confusing because I didn't provide the full range. Basically I have a time range between 17:00-02:00 and need 11pm to fall between these ranges. 

11pm > 5pm works but then fails on 11pm < 2am

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a *lot* more context - and ideally multiple examples of test data with expected results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare time values in AM , PM format in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414864/compare-time-values-in-am-pm-format-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @HDhani Then you don't want to work with `TimeSpan` but `DateTime` objects.

Comment: @Adriani6 I only have a full date for (a) and only times for (b) though. Is it still possible somehow?

Comment: For any two time-of-day values, it's possible to argue that one time occurs both ***before and after*** the other. Thus, this conundrum, in its current form, is ambiguous.

Comment: @HDhani Maybe, perhaps you can hack it together by creating a date object of a given date and change time on it? As in, take date from (a) add one day, set time from (b) and compare this way... but all this depends if this conflicts with anything else and  how accurate it is on your data set.

Comment: @Adriani6 Ye that makes sense, I'll have to copy the date and change the time on it but also +1 day to it somehow. Seems like the only way to do this unless someone knows a way to convert "02:00 + 1 day" to a TimeSpan object

Comment: @HDhani It is indeed possible, but I'd expect the code to be much more readable if there wasn't a complex conversion into Timespans.

Comment: @HDhani Why are you still talking about the `TimeSpan` ? It can only hold values of `00:00` to `23:59` and would never work as you'd be back to what you came here with. Work with `DateTime` and compare the objects, don't use `TimeSpan` since your hours are outwith the same day.

Comment: All sorted, thanks @Adriani6 for the tips :)